# Proxy setting for git+https on CLI not working

Tags: pip

I am trying to send git requests through a http proxy for a MISP installation.

for `git clone` it is working fine but for example:

```
SUDO_WWW $PATH_TO_MISP/venv/bin/pip install --proxy=0.0.0.0:8080 -U python-magic git+https://github.com/kbandla/pydeep.git plyara lief
```

[image]

it is working for the `pip install` but not for the git+https
I changed it to

```
SUDO_WWW $PATH_TO_MISP/venv/bin/pip install --proxy=0.0.0.0:8080 -U python-magic git git -c http.proxy=0.0.0.0:8080 clone https://github.com/kbandla/pydeep.git plyara lief
```

[image]